# Keep iOS app alive for more than 3 minutes after didEnterRegion - geofencing - geolocation - background modes

Tags: ios, background, geolocation, geofencing

Here is what I'm trying to perform. My app is supposed to give a notification after you spend an amount of time in a region (between 5-10 min).

I have used CLLocationManager and region monitoring but it's not accurate enough. Basically it sends me an event on didEnterRegion but even I set my region radius at 15 meters, the real radius is more like 100 to 200 meters.

The workaround I have found is to keep the app running in background and get an update on location (didUpdateLocations) every minute and work with this to check if the user is in the region or not. This was largely inspired by this https://github.com/voyage11/Location/tree/master/Location . It actually works great for what I want to do.

The thing is: it only works if the app is in background but not killed and also for a reason that I cannot explain it stops running after 2 to 7 hours.

My idea is to start tracking location when a user enters a region. So when I enter a region the app wakes up and didEnterRegion is called and I start my background task (it's actually a background task manager that restarts a new background task every minute - see in the github mention above for the code) and location updates. This works but after 3 minutes the app crashes with a message like

> permittedBackgroundDuration: 180.000000 reason: finishTask preventSuspend preventIdleSleep preventSuspendOnSleep

I would like it to run at least for 10 minutes. Or I would like to keep background tracking alive even if the app is killed (like the Moves app does for example).

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

PS: of course I have allowed Location updates in background modes ;)